# Access data from dynamic schema database with spring DATA REST?

Tags: spring-boot, schema, spring-data-rest

How I can get list Api data from dynamic schema **database** after logged with **spring data rest** ?

{
"cause": null,
"message": "Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMetadata.isExported()" because "metadata" is null"
}